# Get nearest locations using latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table `hotspots`

```
id  name  date
1   foo   2011-06-15 15:10:34
2   bar   2011-07-02 16:45:18
```

And a table `locations`

```
hotspotid  zipcode  latitude  longitude
1          90001    xxxxx     xxxxx
2          45802    xxxxx     xxxxx
```

How can i list the hotspots nearby to a specific latitude and longitude with miles limit using an SQL query?

P.S. i'd like a pure SQL solution but php is ok if it's needed.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you have distance table? If not, you need to create one.

Comment: For example, there is a lat/lon table [here](http://www.populardata.com/downloads.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need a geographic location for each hotspot ideally using latitude and longitude. You can use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to go through each record and store lat/long.

Then you can [match nearby hotspots with this SQL query](http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/) and order by distance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i forgot to put the latitude and longitude fields there. i have those.

Comment: Then just use the SQL query to calculate distance between lat/longs and order by distance, you should be all set :)

Comment: @Tak i see, thanks for the link, i'm stuck at joining the locations with the hotspots in order to use that query :/

Answer (score 0):

Just browsing I found [this link](http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-zip-code-range-and-distance-calculation.html) though I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for.

Here is a post which better describes the library.  This isn't an SQl-based answer though you could take the lats/longs, dump them into the db and code up a distance query.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure SQL solution, you can look at databases like

http://www.zip-codes.com

If you're looking for a free solution, I've used the maxminds ip address databases before, but their zip code accuracy is very poor. Also, the maxminds database is intended for lookup up a location from an IP address.

If you want to look up the location of a zip code, you can sign up for a Google Maps API key and use their geolocation lookup service. This solution most likely would require PHP or javascript to do the lookup. But the service is well documented, and very effective in my experience.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Geolocation

Answer (score 0):

what you are calculating is the 'great circle distance' between two pairs of lat and long values.

this can be done in SQL, and especially if you want to pull the calculation out and make it into a database procedure...  just order by the distance when computed

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about things within a certain distance of the points, you should have a look at this:

http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for nearest location

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180)  + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` 
FROM `members` 
HAVING `distance`<=’10’ 
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```